# How to Fix my Web Cookies Session Timeout

Tags: php

Am trying to make my cookies timeout unlimited.
When users login it usually log them out after sometimes in that same day.
Presently am out of Ideas, i need help on how to fix it.

This is the code below.

```
$CookieExpire    =    86400;    
$time    =    30    *    $CookieExpire;    
$time    =    time()    +    $time;    
$key    =    $username . date('mY');    
$key    =    strtoupper(md5($key));    
setcookie    ("sessionkey",     "$key",    "$time");    
setcookie    ("user",    "$username",    "$time");    
setcookie    ("password",    "$password",    "$time");
```

Comment: remove `"` around `$time`,it should be `int`. setcookie    ("sessionkey",     "$key",   $time);

Answer (score 0):

md5 is not secure you can use jwttoken to make token and store you data there. And to store jwt token ( for now you cab store string generating by md5 ) in cookie and make it for 100 years like this.

```
setcookie( "user", $username, time()+(60*60*24*365*100) );
```

More about cookie : http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: Let me gv it a try and see

Comment: Hello Sir! The code totaly went error or pls can you recode it for me just like the way it should be.

Comment: May be problem is on other area.